# find.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript

how can i use the list (that is named `myjson`) in other js file?!

exports is not defined...

the first line that is `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });`

is originally not in here. But i added.

And still have this problem.

How can i use 'myjson' in other js file??

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); var
 dataone = document.querySelector('#dataone'); var datatwo =
 document.querySelector('#datatwo'); var datathree =
 document.querySelector('#datathree'); var datafour =
 document.querySelector('#datafour'); // var findingokay =
 document.querySelector('.findingokay');

 var data1 = 0; var data2 = 0; var data3 = 0; var data4 = 0;



 var myjson = [data1, data2, data3, data4]; exports.myjson = myjson;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2TuU.png)

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is`enter code here` not defined
     at find.js:2

-

---

---

Answer (score 0):

Use compilers like babel, browserify to make use of latest js features and these compilers will convert your code to browser supported js version.

Have a look at
https://babeljs.io/

Comment: i used it, but there isn't any change!

Comment: I think this is also the same problem. Please check.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43870504/2003630